# @BeforeStep defined in ItemProcessor and ItemWitter is not getting called with spring batch partitioning

Tags: spring-batch, partitioning, spring-batch-tasklet, spring-batch-job-monitoring

We were moving our spring batch implementations to use partitions. After making changes now the @BeforeStep is not getting called which is inside our processor and writter.

Sample code here,

```
@Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter<EmployeeTaxDetail> customerItemWriter()
    {
        ItemWriter<EmployeeTaxDetail> itemWriter = appContext.getBean(EmployeeTaxCalculationWriter.class);
        return itemWriter;
    }
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemProcessor<EmployeeDetail, EmployeeTaxDetail> processor() {
        ItemProcessor<EmployeeDetail, EmployeeTaxDetail> itemProcessor = appContext.getBean(EmployeeTaxCalculationProcessor.class);
        return itemProcessor;
    }
    
    // Master
    @Bean
    public Step step1() 
    {
        return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
                .partitioner(slaveStep().getName(), partitioner())
                .listener(processor())
                .listener(customerItemWriter())
                .step(slaveStep())
                .gridSize(5)
                .taskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
                .build();
    }
    
    // slave step
    @Bean
    public Step slaveStep() 
    {
        
        return new StepBuilder("slaveStep", jobRepository)
                .<EmployeeDetail, EmployeeTaxDetail>chunk(10,transactionManager)
                .reader(pagingItemReader(null,null))
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(customerItemWriter())
                .build();
    }
```

EmployeeTaxCalculationWriter and EmployeeTaxCalculationProcessor are like,

```
@Component
public class EmployeeTaxCalculationWriter extends AbstractItemWriter<EmployeeTaxDetail> {

  /** The febp data source provider. */
  @Autowired
  private FEBPDataSourceProvider febpDataSourceProvider;

  /** The Constant LOGGER. */
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeTaxCalculationWriter.class.getName());

  /** The Constant INSERT_REPORT_HISTORY_QUERY. */
  private static final String INSERT_EMP_TAX_QUERY = "INSERT INTO FEBP_EMP_TAX_DETAIL_TEST " + "(ENTITY_ID, EMP_ID, EMP_TAX) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

  /**
   * Execute write.
   *
   * @param chunk the chunk
   * @throws Exception the exception
   */
  @Override
  protected void executeWrite(Chunk<? extends EmployeeTaxDetail> chunk) throws Exception {
    saveToTaxDetail(chunk);

  }

  /**
   * Save to tax detail.
   *
   * @param chunk the chunk
   */
  private void saveToTaxDetail(Chunk<? extends EmployeeTaxDetail> chunk) {

    List<EmployeeTaxDetail> employeeTaxDetailList = (List<EmployeeTaxDetail>) chunk.getItems();
    DataSource febpDBSrc = getFebpDataSource();
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(febpDBSrc);
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(INSERT_EMP_TAX_QUERY, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
      @Override
      public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
        EmployeeTaxDetail empTaxDetail = employeeTaxDetailList.get(i);
        ps.setString(1, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        ps.setString(2, empTaxDetail.getEmpId());
        ps.setLong(3, empTaxDetail.getTaxAmount());
      }

      @Override
      public int getBatchSize() {
        return employeeTaxDetailList.size();
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Gets the febp data source.
   *
   * @return the febp data source
   */
  private DataSource getFebpDataSource() {
    return febpDataSourceProvider.getDataSource(FengThreadLocal.getTenantId(), "FEBP");
  }

}
```

and
Component

```
public class EmployeeTaxCalculationProcessor extends AbstractItemProcessor<EmployeeDetail, EmployeeTaxDetail> {

  /**
   * Execute process.
   *
   * @param item the item
   * @return the employee tax detail
   * @throws Exception the exception
   */
  @Override
  protected EmployeeTaxDetail executeProcess(EmployeeDetail item) throws Exception {
    EmployeeTaxDetail employeeTaxDetail = new EmployeeTaxDetail();
    employeeTaxDetail.setEmpId(item.getEmpId());
    employeeTaxDetail.setTaxAmount((long) (item.getEmpSalary() * .1));
    if(item.getEmpId().endsWith("2"))
    {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    }
    return employeeTaxDetail;
  }

}
And inside AbstractItemWriter we have 
public abstract class AbstractItemWriter<T> implements ItemWriter<T> {

  /** The parameters. */
  private JobParameters parameters;

  /**
   * Write.
   *
   * @param chunk the chunk
   * @throws Exception the exception
   */
  @Override
  public void write(@NonNull Chunk<? extends T> chunk) throws Exception {
      JobParameter jobParameter = null;
      if( parameters!=null) {
     jobParameter = parameters.getParameter(FebpAPIConstants.FEBP_THREAD_LOCAL);
    }
    if (jobParameter != null) {
      ApplicationThreadLocal.populateThreadLocalData(
          (ApplicationThreadLocalState) JsonUtil.readJsonValue(jobParameter.getValue().toString(), ApplicationThreadLocalState.class, false));
    }
    executeWrite(chunk);
  }

  /**
   * Execute write.
   *
   * @param chunk the chunk
   * @throws Exception the exception
   */
  protected abstract void executeWrite(@NonNull Chunk<? extends T> chunk) throws Exception;

  /**
   * Before step.
   *
   * @param stepExecution the step execution
   */
  **@BeforeStep**
  public void beforeStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
    parameters = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getJobParameters();
  }

  /**
   * Gets the parameters.
   *
   * @return the parameters
   */
  public JobParameters getParameters() {
    return parameters;
  }
} and inside AbstractItemProcessor we have
public abstract class AbstractItemProcessor<I, O> implements ItemProcessor<I, O> {

  /** The parameters. */
  private JobParameters parameters;

  /**
   * Process.
   *
   * @param item the item
   * @return the o
   * @throws Exception the exception
   */
  @Override
  public O process(I item) throws Exception {
      JobParameter jobParameter = null;
      if( parameters!=null) {
     jobParameter = parameters.getParameter(FebpAPIConstants.FEBP_THREAD_LOCAL);
    }
    if (jobParameter != null) {
      ApplicationThreadLocal.populateThreadLocalData(
          (ApplicationThreadLocalState) JsonUtil.readJsonValue(jobParameter.getValue().toString(), ApplicationThreadLocalState.class, false));
    }
    return executeProcess(item);
  }

  /**
   * Execute write.
   *
   * @param item the item
   * @return the o
   * @throws Exception the exception
   */
  protected abstract O executeProcess(I item) throws Exception;

  /**
   * Before step.
   *
   * @param stepExecution the step execution
   */
  @BeforeStep
  public void beforeStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
    parameters = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getJobParameters();
  }

  /**
   * Gets the parameters.
   *
   * @return the parameters
   */
  public JobParameters getParameters() {
    return parameters;
  }

}
```

Now the process method is getting called for each processor and writter call but @BeforeStep is stopped getting called after introducing partitioning.

Comment: What if you remove `@StepScope` on `customerItemWriter()` and `processor()`? This annotation is not needed based on the code you shared.

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine, Thanks for your input.
If I remove StepScope it gets called. Now the question is StepScope not useful for restarting/resuming the failed partition? I had added the same as I thought its needed for restarting the failed partition or resuming the unprocessed partition in case of server crash to maintain the state.

Comment: The step scope is used for late binding of step context attributes (from the execution context, job parameters, etc), or to have a different instance of a component per step execution. In the case you shared, it won't affect restartability.

Comment: @ Mahmoud Ben Hassine, Thanks for the explanation. If I have some scenarios where we might need  step scope as well,  what is the solution?

Comment: Scoped beans are not incompatible with restartability. What i am saying is that in the specific case you shared, there is no need for a scoped bean. But if you need a scoped bean, use one. You can have a scoped bean that is a step listener as well (ie that implements `StepExecutionListener` or has one of its methods annotated with `BeforeStep`). But in that case, there is probably no need to scope the bean since it would have already a stepExecution in scope.

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine"But if you need a scoped bean, use one. You can have a scoped bean that is a step listener as well (ie that implements StepExecutionListener or has one of its methods annotated with BeforeStep)." --> If you see I have added writter and processor as listeners as well, Bean public Step step1() 
{return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository).partitioner(slaveStep().getName(), partitioner()).listener(processor()).listener(customerItemWriter()) .step(slaveStep()).gridSize(5).taskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
.build();} This did not work, is this what you meant?

Comment: As mentioned, it didn't work because of the step-scope, which is not needed in that case. Have you tried to implement `StepExecutionListener` instead of the annotation-based way?

Comment: For now have removed step-scope as you suggested, will update you once I try StepExecutionListener. Thanks